# Windows Server Core - Change Display Language

Tags: command-line, powershell, windows-server, localization

I'm playing around with an image of Windows Server Core for self-education and I've hit a frustrating stump.

The image I used to install the server is in German. I'm fluent in German so it's not an actual problem, but I would much prefer to work in an English environment.

Now, I've changed system locale to English as well as UILanguageOverride and user input languages all to English. But both command prompt, powershell and Task Manager are all still in German.

I'm still new to the server environment, so I'd like to ask how you actually change the system display language through cmd/powershell.

Answer (score 2):

Check which language packages you have installed with `DISM /online /Get-Intl`. Then check to see which one is active, and where, with these commands:

```
Get-Culture | Format-List -Property *
Get-WinSystemLocale
Get-WinUserLanguageList
```

Set the one you want to use with these commands (I'm using en-US as an example):

```
Set-WinSystemLocale en-US
Set-WinUserLanguageList en-US -Force
```

Or set it just for the current user account:

```
Set-WinUILanguageOverride
```

To load the new display language, `logoff` then log back in, or set it for the current session:

```
[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture = 'en-US'
[cultureinfo]::CurrentUICulture = 'en-US'
```

Edit: Adding some alternative commands:

```
Set-Culture en-US
Set-WinSystemLocale -SystemLocale en-US
Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList (New-WinUserLanguageList -Language en-US) -Force
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already tried changing the locale and language list, and after doing it once again just in case, command prompt and task manager are still in German. 
Get-Culture tells me that en-DE is installed and en-US is the fallback language. Tried changing manually to en-US, still nothing.

Comment: @Arcturus I've added some additional commands to try out